# Decal Batch doesn't work on all devices Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I tried rendering using Libgdx's DecalBatch on my phone and my friend's phone. It's rendering a 2D image with thickness.

A decal at the front and back side is created, then individual decals for every pixel at its side.

Then, I flush (render) the decals.

On my phone, it gave this result:
[image: My Phone (this works)]
*It worked as expected.*

However, on my friend's phone, it didn't render at all:
[image: Friend's phone (this didn't work)]
*It didn't work as expected.*

**How do I fix this? Or is it a bug in Libgdx?**

Comment: Is your game 3D?

Comment: Not really, the only 3d thing is that (the problem). It's a 2d texture with a "thickness", rendered using DecalBatch.

Comment: It may be too late to make a refactoring, but Sprites are 3d thing and they add unnecessary complexity to the 2d world. Decals are sorted by DecalBatch somehow (on cpu or maybe even on gpu) by their distance from the camera or with a custom sorter (if you provide one). There may be many reasons why it does not render - most probably, it is just hidden behind the other graphics (those in background). Maybe your DecalBatch has too small buffer size and flushes its vertices (of graphics closer to the camera) and then you draw the background. Maybe there's an issue somewhere else in depth sorting

Comment: I've used decals for years without issues from any of my customers across hundreds of device models, so it's unlikely that it's caused by a libGDX bug. Could be a bug in your shader that's not present on a specific device. Or it could be an issue with precision in the depth buffer if your decal strategy has depth sorting turned on. To rule out the shader, check if the ShaderProgram has an error, use `shaderProgram.isCompiled()` and if that's false, log the `shaderProgram.getLog()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working now!

I forgot to add this one line of code:

```
Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I mainly forgot to put the depth buffer bit.
Anyways, thank you to everyone who has helped.